# Automatically assign Wikidata URIs to a list of names

Tags: xml, sparql, semantic-web, assign, wikidata

I have a list a plant names in various languages (botanical names; English, German and loads of historical variants of these two languages) in XML (however, transforming it into whatever serialization won't be a problem). This is what it looks like now:

```
<ingredients>
  <ingredient>
    <lemma>Rosmarinus officinalis L.</lemma>
    <syn lang="deu">Rosmarin</syn>
    <syn lang="ang">boþen</syn>
    <syn lang="ang">feldmædere</syn>
    <syn lang="ang">lauendie</syn>
    <syn lang="eng">rosemary</syn>
    <syn lang="ang">sundēaw</syn>
  </ingredient>
  <ingredient>
    ...
</ingredients>
```

Now I was wondering if there was a way to assign Wikidata and/or other URIs from controlled vocabularies automatically to this list. Of course considering a manageable error rate for strings that don't match 100%. What approaches could be used to get:

```
 <ingredient wikidata="Q122679">
    <lemma>Rosmarinus officinalis L.</lemma>
    ...
```

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: SPARQL lookup via `rdfs:label` property. Might fail indeed because 1) homonyms 2) no exact matching label in the dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to say that [OpenRefine](https://openrefine.org) does exactly what I needed!